# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

*Мы, как сеятели, — разбрасываем семена, они должны взойти*. В этом предложении правильно расставлены знаки препинания? Есть ли здесь сравнительный оборот?

Answer (score 3):

После редактирования:

(1) **Мы как сеятели — разбрасываем семена,  которые должны взойти.**

Здесь бессоюзная связь в сложном предложении с  пояснительным значением, ставится тире или двоеточие. Оборот в роли именной части сказуемого.

(2) **Мы, как сеятели, разбрасываем семена, которые должны взойти.**

Это обособленный сравнительный оборот.